# The difference between returning a recursive method and using a returning method?

Tags: java

I am in a java class at my highschool so I am very new to writing code.

For a recursive method, how does using the word return effect the output? I assume return means and end to the program.

For this program, what would random(15) output? Would it just keep looping until inevitably c was 10 and then return 80? If possible, please break this down step by step as I am having trouble understanding it.

```
public int random(int c) 
{
    if( int c > 10)
        return random(c - 1);
    return c * 8;
}
```

How does this code differ from this code, that does not have the return keyword.

```
public int random(int c) 
{
    if( int c > 10)
        random(c - 1);
    return c * 8;
}
```

Comment: "_this code ... that does not have the return keyword._" It **does** have the return keyword, twice. In fact, I can't see any difference between the 2 code samples. "_For this program, what would random(15) output?_" Just run the code and see.

Comment: Both your code samples are the same. Please correct it.

Comment: "_please break this down step by step as I am having trouble understanding it_" Look up a tutorial on how to use a debugger as that is exactly what it allows you to do - step through your code one line at a time.

Comment: like @csmckelvey mentioned, just run it and see what the result is. If the result alone doesn't help try stepping through with a debugger and be sure to use the step into option when you encounter the line `return random(c - 1)`

Answer (score 1):

First of all I'm not sure why you need to ask this question, in fact I think you understand the concept of recursive methods quite good.

**First Snippet**

As you explained correctly random(15) returns a value of 80.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println("Result: " + random(15));
}

private static int random(int c) {
    if (c > 10) {
        System.out.println("c is greater than 10");
        return random(c - 1);
    }
    System.out.println("multiplying c=" + c + " by 8");
    return c * 8;
}
```

Output:

```
run:
c is greater than 10
c is greater than 10
c is greater than 10
c is greater than 10
c is greater than 10

multiplying c=10 by 8

Result: 80
BUILD SUCCESSFUL (total time: 0 seconds)
```

Just for explanation, the variable c is decreased by 1 five times and then finally multiplied by 8.

**Second Snippet**

I just assume that your second method should look something like this:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println("Result: " + random(15));
}

private static int random(int c) {
    if (c > 10) {
        System.out.println("c is greater than 10");
        random(c - 1);
    }
    System.out.println("multiplying c=" + c + " by 8");
    return c * 8;
}
```

This time, the output looks different and also the result is different.

Output:

```
run:
c is greater than 10 // method a
c is greater than 10 // b
c is greater than 10 // c
c is greater than 10 // d
c is greater than 10 // e

multiplying c=10 by 8 // --> random(c - 1); in method e
multiplying c=11 by 8 // happening in method e
multiplying c=12 by 8 // d
multiplying c=13 by 8 // c
multiplying c=14 by 8 // b
multiplying c=15 by 8 // a

Result: 120
BUILD SUCCESSFUL (total time: 0 seconds)
```

You can see that your variable c is decreased by 1 in each method (a - e) and then equal to 10-15. At the end only the last multiplication matters, which is 15 * 8 of course, and the result of this operation is then displayed as the result.

Cobra_8

Answer (score 0):

Even though you should probably do some research about recursive methods, I'll try to explain the difference as simple as possible.

In your first method, if `c > 10` then the method returns the result of the call to itself with the parameter `c - 1`, this means that as long as c is greater than 10, the method will get called and c will decrease by one until it's equal to 10 to then return 80 (10 * 8).

The second method does nothing special, in fact you can say that it's like only returning `c * 8`, why? Because you're calling the same method with `c - 1` but you're not using the result and the code gets out of the if statement and goes to the `return c * 8;` so no matter how much is `c`, the result will always be `c * 8`.

On the other hand with the first method, it'll get called recursively until c reachs 10 and will then return 80 back to the very first call of the method (see https://introcs.cs.princeton.edu/java/23recursion/ for more informations).